# Jedi-vim doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, jedi-vim

I have a issue with VIM. I'm trying to install jedi-vim with Vundle plugin, and typing this 
"example":

```
import math  
math.
```

after dot i get popup with autocomplete. Really not bad, but, i cant choose function/method/class/etc. what i want (arrows somehow doesn't worked, when show popup with autocomplete and preview of first function/method/class/etc. which automatically selected)

At my .vimrc file:

```
let g:jedi#popup_select_first = 0  
let g:jedi#goto_command = "<leader>g"  
let g:jedi#get_definition_command = "<leader>d"  
let g:jedi#rename_command = "<leader>r"  
let g:jedi#related_names_command = "<leader>n"  
let g:jedi#autocompletion_command = "<C-Space>"
```

P.S. Maybe incompatible with some plugin, which installed also by Vundle:

- NERDTree
- NERDCommenter
- TagBar
- minibufexpl.vim
- FixedTaskList.vim
- conque-term
- vim-snippets
- vim-snipmate
- vim-addon-mw-utils
- tlib_vim
- git-vim
- vim-gitgutter
- vim-airline
- python-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same problem as you. I am new to vim so I only use a few plugins:

- nerdtree
- jedi-vim
- supertab
- taglist
- vimwiki
- minibufexpl

After trying and error, I found out `jedi-vim` is incompatible with `minibufexpl`. So I deleted `minibufexpl` and everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

From [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/master/README.rst) documentation

Note that the python-mode VIM plugin seems to conflict with jedi-vim, therefore you should disable it before enabling jedi-vim.

Answer (score 0):

Jedi-vim is autocomplete plugin. If you disable rope plugin in python-mode you can use this plugins together.

ll you need to do is add the plugin to the vundle list and turn off Rope by replacing the `let g:pymode_rope = 1` with `let g:pymode_rope = 0`  --> http://unlogic.co.uk/2013/02/08/vim-as-a-python-ide/#python-mode